# datagrid as excel editor in c#

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, datagridview, openxml

I have a requirement to display data from excel document in a C# win form datagrid. Add formula functionality of excel and apply in the datagrid value. When saving datagrid values to a excel value save same like excel file including formulaes.

Can any one help me how to do this one.

Is it can be doable through OpenXml or OleDB because I don't want to depend upon MS Office installation in client place.

Thanks in advance.

Sharma

Answer (score 0):

this requirement of yours sounds like a project itself ! but I am sure this can get you started http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17853/Implementing-an-Excel-like-formula-engine

Comment: Thanks legendinmaking,

This is one form of a project where user has to edit the excel document.